How to fix paint/wall around this outlet/tile/trim to improve appearance?
We had a pipe boot on the roof crack and had some water leaking into the kitchen area. The water went down the side of the wall and mostly came out near the outlet plug. This got the drywall around the area wet, probably compromising its integrity to some extent and also caused the paint to start peeling off. In the picture you can see some of the peeling paint as well as what I assume is a drywall joint line on the left. This happened some time ago so the drywall is completely dry at this point.
I'd like to repaint this area, but want it to look as good as possible. Of course I will remove any flaking paint. My concerns are

Making sure the surface post-paint removal is prepared well for new paint.
Eliminating the drywall seam line to the left.
Making the bottom of the painted area merge well into the tile that's present below so it looks uniform with the rest of the wall.

I would pull out all the damaged drywall and do a patch of it, but I'm concerned that might be a bigger job than I have time for at the moment. It seems like that would entail removing the tile, possibly removing the window trim to the right (barely in the picture), and maybe even separating apart the pieces of the kitchen countertops and pulling them back from the wall. So I'm hoping to be able to work in the exposed area and do as best as I can.

At the bottom of the painted area, you can see what I assume is some grout from the tile application that is above the old paint.

If I remove the paint, I'll presumably take this grout off with it. I'm wondering how best to repair this interface between the two materials. Should I paint just down to the tile? Should I paint and then apply a small amount of grout or something on top of the paint so it looks consistent? Should that grout never have never been placed up above the tile in the first place? Plenty of Youtube videos show you how to put on tile, but they seem to mostly tile an entire wall or directly up to a cabinet, and I haven't seen how one is supposed to end a line of tile on the wall.
Thoughts on best way to proceed here?

A curious spot, but that looks like that got wet over time, repeatedly perhaps.

The leak was on and off present for a couple of days before we realized what the water on the counter was, but I don't know that the period of being intermittently wet was longer than a week or so. That said, I don't know what the situation was like with the former owner, so it is possible.

As long as the leak was repaired, then a fix is worthwhile. It will be simple enough, a little scraping, a little sanding a little drywall mud, and so on. I am sure one of the guys here will fill you in. I gotta g to work.

Yes, we’ve since replaced the boot and the roof itself so it certainly doesn’t leak now.

You should be able to fix this without effecting the grout:

Remove the faceplate
Use a sharp utility knife and score the paint just above the grout line
Scrape off the loose paint and any loose mud
Apply a coat of drywall mud (use a damp/wet sponge to wipe any mud off the grout)
Sand and apply a thin layer of mud to fix any imperfections
Sand
Prime
Paint
Reinstall the face plate

